# GRPC CPP Setup for Windows using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, grpc, rpc

I am currently working on setting up GRPC client and server in windows using CPP language. IDE i want to use is Visual Studio. I am not able to get any proper channel to set up the environment.  Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: May I ask that the `environment`  means the environment construction of GRPC?

Comment: Environment in my case is Setup that i need to do in Visual Studio 2017 for building and running GRPC using  CPP client and server.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with CMake, MinGW and the Open Folder feature of VS2017. That works fine!

Comment: Hi, this is nether a solution to the question nor something that can provide the person that asks the question enough help. Please do not post such answers in the future, thanks~

Comment: But this is a solution to the question. What do you expect here ? That i post a lot of config files ?